# Parse a complex JSON result

Tags: java, json

I have a json (result) like the below , i need the value of Key "extra", that is "contact office".
I tried the below code, but it did not work, can you help?

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result.toString().trim());
JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("student").getJSONArray("department").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("classes");
String val=json.getString("extra");
```

// JSON Example

```
{

"student": [

{
    "department" : [

        {
            "classes" : [

                {

                "grade" : "A",
                "fine"  : "No"
                },
                {

                "grade" : "B",
                "fine"  : "Yes",
                "extra" : "contact office"
                },
                {

                "grade" : "C",
                "fine"  : "NA"
                }
                ],
        }
        ],

}
],
```

}

Comment: Pleas put your code in a code block and tell us what didn't work.

Comment: @Oleg,  code segment is already there in the question.

Comment: What means *but it did not work*? Any error message or what is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` a few times, not sure exactly what I had to change but the following will work:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString().trim());
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject
        .getJSONArray("student").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("department").getJSONObject(0)
        .getJSONArray("classes");
String val = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).getString("extra");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a full sample? If so it doesn't start out as an array. Student is and object not an array. If it is just a sample of one item in the array then you're okay.

The second thing I noticed is: `getJSONObject("classes")`. Classes is an array not an object, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to consider using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath). You could do something like this -

```
String[] extraValues = JsonPath.read(json, "$.student[0].department[0].classes[*].extra");
```